# Multithreading in Python setting _thread attribute

Tags: multithreading

I see a line of code in a few lines of codes that aim to do threading:

```
    thread = Thread(target = self.run)
    thread.start()
    setattr(self, "_thread", thread)
```

What do the last line of code do, what does setting  _thread=thread achieve?

Answer (score 0):

In python underscores are used to indicate what in other languages might be private attributes.
[PEP8:](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

> _single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. from M import * does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.

```
setattr(self, "_thread", thread)
```

should be doing basically the same as

```
self._thread = thread
```

It can be found in the python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

Why he is doing the first instead of the latter I can't explain either, it might be easier to answer if you provide more context.

Comment: Throughout the code, this is the only place that is in reference to _thread, my guess is that this does something in the threading process? setting this attribute to thread is for what purpose?

Comment: Well the purpose of `self._x = x` is usually to store a value, or in this case a reference to your `thread`.
Without this line the `thread` object would be deleted at the end of the method (or scope if it's in another scope, impossible to tell from these three lines).